# Returning multiple values from an INSERT and inserting both into another table

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have the following Oracle procedure (I've take some detail out to make the question more general:

```
create or replace
procedure Insert_Row (foo IN VARCHAR2,  
                      buzz in VARCHAR2,
                      t_in MyType)
is
l_cur_id number;
begin
    insert into table1 (foo,buzz)
returning bar into l_cur_id;
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..t_in.count LOOP
insert into table2 (bar, something)
    values(l_cur_id,t_in(i));
    commit;
END LOOP;
end;
end;
```

All it does is insert a row into `table1`, gets the ID from the row just inserted into `table1` and uses it to insert into `table2`.

Here's the type I'm using above:

```
create or replace
TYPE MyType AS VARRAY(200) OF VARCHAR2(50);
```

**My question:** How can I insert `buzz` into `table2`?  I.e. a second value.  I think must be simple because I already the value of `buzz` before I insert.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Solved straight after posting - typical!  Will post the solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, all I add to do was this:

Change from:

```
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..t_in.count LOOP
insert into table2 (bar, something)
    values(l_cur_id,t_in(i));
    commit;
END LOOP;
```

to this:

```
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..t_in.count LOOP
insert into table2 (bar, something,buzz)
    values(l_cur_id,t_in(i),buzz);
    commit;
END LOOP;
```

so obvious :-S.

Comment: It's advisable not to commit in a storage procedure, leave it up to a calling application. Especially do not commit in a loop.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, I will implement this change.  +1.